# Able to cascade two ComboBoxes, need to cascade a 3rd ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I need to create 3 cascading ComboBoxes (A, B and C) with databinding. From the examples I have seen I am able to get two working (A and B), but I'm not sure how to wire up ComboBox C whose ItemsSource should be dependent on the selection made in ComboBox B. So, just as there are a set of Reasons displayed in ComboBox B for each Category displayed in ComboBox A, I need to display a set of SubReasons in ComboBox C for each Reason displayed in ComboBox B.  As the selections change so does the underlying drop-down list values.  I hope that makes sense.  Is there some way to bind to a ViewModel property to achieve this or ???.

> XAML

```
     <ComboBox x:Name="cbxA"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectCategoryList}" 
                SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedProject.Category}"                      
                DisplayMemberPath="Category"/>
     <ComboBox x:Name="cbxB"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbxA, Path=SelectedItem.Reasons}" 
                Text="{Binding Path=SelectedProject.Reason}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
     <ComboBox x:Name="cbxC"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbxB, Path=SelectedItem.SubReasons}" 
                Text="{Binding Path=SelectedProject.SubReason}"/>
```

> ViewModel

```
    private Project selectedProject;

    public Project SelectedProject
    {
        get { return selectedProject; }
        set
        {
            if(selectedProject != value)
            {
                selectedProject = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedProject");
            }
        }
    }

    public List<ProjectCategory> ProjectCategoryList
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<ProjectCategory>()
            {
                new ProjectCategory
                {
                    Category = "One",
                    Reasons = new List<Reason>
                    {
                        new Reason() { Name = "A", SubReasons = new List<String> { "1", "2", "3" }},
                        new Reason() { Name = "B", SubReasons = new List<String> { "4", "5", "6" }},
                        new Reason() { Name = "C", SubReasons = new List<String> { "7", "8", "9" }}, 

                    }
                },
                new ProjectCategory
                {
                    Category = "Two",
                    Reasons = new List<Reason>
                    {
                        new Reason() { Name = "D", SubReasons = Enumerable.Empty<string>()},
                        new Reason() { Name = "E", SubReasons = Enumerable.Empty<string>()},
                        new Reason() { Name = "F", SubReasons = Enumerable.Empty<string>()},
                    }
                },
                new ProjectCategory
                {
                    Category = "Three",
                    Reasons = new List<Reason>
                    {
                        new Reason() { Name = "J", SubReasons = Enumerable.Empty<string>()},
                        new Reason() { Name = "K", SubReasons = Enumerable.Empty<string>()},
                    }
                },
            };
        }
    }
```

> ProjectCategory.cs

```
public class ProjectCategory
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Reason> Reasons { get; set; }
}

public class Reason
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SubReasons { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where are your sub reasons defined?

Comment: And where are `SelectedItem` and `SelectedProject` defined?

Comment: Currently they're not defined as I'm not sure where to define them.  I had created another class similar in structure to ProjectCategory.cs but unsure how to include that in the binding.  SelectedItem is the ComboBox.SelectedItem property and I'll add the rest now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Reasons` property of the `ProjectCategory` class should return an `IEnumerable<Reason>` instead of an `IEnumerable<string>` and the `Reason` class should include a `Name` (or `Reason`) property of type `string` and an `IEnumerable<string>` of sub reasons.

You can then bind `cbxC` the same way:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cbxA"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectCategoryList}" 
            SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedProject.Category}"                      
            DisplayMemberPath="Category"/>
 <ComboBox x:Name="cbxB"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbxA, Path=SelectedItem.Reasons}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
 <ComboBox x:Name="cbxC"
      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbxb, Path=SelectedItem.SubReasons}" />
```

---

```
public class ProjectCategory
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Reason> Reasons { get; set; }
}

public class Reason
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SubReasons { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed to get this working the way I wanted, thanks a bunch.